# How to add custom tags to rich text field in SDL Tridion?

Tags: xml, tridion

In SDL Tridion 2011 SP1, I want to allow custom XML tags (nodes) inside rich text field (RTF) such as

```
<dynamicVariable name='ABC'></dynamicVariable>
```

This triggers the error

> Field 'text' contains invalid markup

How do I allow such custom tags?

Comment: Can you specify which version of SDL Tridion you are using?

Comment: Also, exactly which tag are you adding?

Comment: I am using SDL TRIDION 2011 SP1. I am trying to add that user defined xml tag: <dynamicVariable name='ABC'></dynamicVariable>

Comment: I previously said XML tags do not belong in RTF, but am updating the question and my response to clarify when this would be appropriate. Also consider "merge field" solutions, _maybe_ an XSLT filter, or changes via Tridion templating.

Comment: Rich Text Fields in Tridion are for storing HTML fragments. Although there are ways to extend the control to allow other tags, these are really only meant to be used to allow new HTML tags (such as <article> or <byline> from HTML5). Storing another type of XML in a rich text field is wrong and will lead to many problems. Why don't you simply use a normal multi-line text field for entering that XML?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a file named TcmXhtml.Config under [Tridion]\web\WebUI\Core\Controls\FormatArea\TcmXhtml where you can specify additional block tags that Tridion should accept in RTF.

Do keep in mind that there's a good reason why Rich Text fields comply to standards like Xhtml.

Comment: _Technical_ problem solved, but what business problem does this introduce, @Murali? Adding custom tags to RTF source can make it harder on your authors. Consider using a _somewhat_ friendlier delimiter like [[ or {{ and transforming it via templating.

Comment: I agree with Alvin. Too often we seek out a solution to our perceived technical problem, and are satisfied with that. <em>Why</em> do you want to embed a dynamic variable? What functional problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I'm thinking this may be appropriate with a proper GUI extension as a more robust version of the merge fields. But it really depends on the business need.

Comment: @AlvinReyes is this the same method I would use to add inline <style> blocks in an RTF? Currently they are being stripped out. I'm guessing that the style tag would go under "new-empty-tags" because it's not a block or inline element.

Comment: After further research it appears the TcmXhtml file is listing settings for Tidy, so now I'm looking into the Tidy documentation to see if theres a way to keep the <style> tags from being removed.

Comment: You might be able to adjust TcmXhtml keep `<style>` tags, but afaik, they really should go in the page `<head>`. A plain text field would be a better fit (or managing these outside of the CMS even). It also depends if front-end developer or regular editors would be managing the style settings.

Comment: <style> tags are invalid inside the <body> tag, that's why they're removed