# how to add the custom elements in the RTF field of a component in SDL Tridion 2011 Sp1

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I want to add custom elements in the source of a Rich Text field in SDL Tridion. Is there any chance to add them by changing the XSL filtering in the Schema?

Example:

I have a RTF field "text" in SDL Tridion. I want to add something like this:

```xml
<text>
    <customelement>the text added through the custom element</customelement>
</text>
```

Can somebody help me on this?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add custom tags to rich text field in SDL Tridion?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613598/how-to-add-custom-tags-to-rich-text-field-in-sdl-tridion)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you're trying to add some HTML5 element in your rich text field.

If you don't want to modify any Tridion installation files, which is something you should try to avoid at all times you could try the following:

- Include a CSS class in your rich text field options.
- Let the users put the css class on a div, span or anchor tag in your rich text field.
- On the front-end with some magic Javascript and jQuery you could try to change the element to the custom element you would like.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you mean to include css class in Allowed styles options while creating the schema. If so where do I write the JavaScript, in the same CSS class? Correct me if I am wrong I have less knowledge in JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, you can add one to the allowed styles options. This if fully supported. 
The Javascript part should be included somewhere in your front-end part. Either include it somewhere in the head part of your outputted HTML part or in an javascript include.

Answer (score 3):

Answered previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9618578/866454)

This might introduce issues that are beyond the scope of Tridion support, so you better be ready to support this yourself.

Comment: could we also add `fb:like` kind of tags with the same mechanism?

Comment: tried it and it does like any tags that require namespace like `fb:like`.

Answer (score 3):

It is probably not necessary to do this. I suspect you should be focussing on your templated output instead.

The standard way for Tridion to store your data in an RTF is as XML in the XHTML namespace. This does not mean that your output needs to comply with this format, any more than the output from a plain text field would need to be plain text.

If you want to have special kinds of data within an RTF field, I would suggest that you use a standard XHTML element, and configure a custom style sheet so that the end users can select the element, and then apply the "specialness" by selecting a class. This is probably a much nicer user experience than having to edit the source tab.

In your templating, you can simply transform these elements into your desired output. I'd suggest using XSLT to do this, or perhaps DOM manipulation, depending on the complexity.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As you expected I was trying to change the xsl of the schema. I was changing output="text" instead it did not work. And I also came to know that we cannot apply xsl transform for simple field. :(
correct me if I am wrong

Comment: The filtering XSLT is indeed only available on Rich Text fields, if you want to apply an XSLT on a plain text field, you can do that either on save of the Component through the Event System or at Publish time using the Template code.

Comment: +1 on standard XHTML (even delimited text) in the CME. This can keep content author or business-friendly options in the CMS while giving development the flexibility to change or manipulate this in templating code or even rendering.